# Getting uninitialized constant from Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm missing something, just not sure what. Sidekiq is up and running fine, I can see it in my terminal.

I have this worker, defined in `app/workers/sqs_worker.rb`

```
class SqsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  require 'aws-sdk'

  def perform
    #do something
  end
end
```

And then in just a test file at `app/test.rb` I have the very simple code:

```
require 'sidekiq'

SqsWorker.new.perform_async
```

When I run the `test.rb` file I get this error: `uninitialized constant SqsWorker (NameError)`

Where did I go astray? I'm running Sidekiq (4.1.4)

I tried killing the running processes and restarting both Sidekiq and Redis to no luck.

Comment: what is your sidekiq version ( `sidekiq -V` ) ?

Comment: Sidekiq (4.1.4) and update the original post..

Comment: Can you try adding this to your `application.rb`:      `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)`

Comment: Yep, tried that before.. didn't work.. urghh.. actually have both these lines:  `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and  `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and no dice.. shoot

Answer (score 0):

`uninitialized constant SqsWorker (NameError)` indicates that your script in `test.rb` is not able to locate class `SqsWorker`

All you need to do is replace `require 'sidekiq'` with `require_relative 'workers/sqs_worker'` to make your script aware about location of `SqsWorker` class.

Comment: That makes sense, but the fix didn't work. Still getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you ran the test.rb from outside of the scope of the application with something like that:

```
ruby app/test.rb
```

But for this purpose, You need to add to your test something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

SqsWorker.new.perform_async
```

And run as this:

```
bundle exec ruby app/test.rb
```

Why do you need this? Because nowadays, the bundler manages your dependencies added to your app and therefore, you need to load the rails environment too and the last will load all the things under `app/` basically.

Comment: Well, this is the first time I'm using Sidekiq and I was just testing to see if it will work for me.. But I just went ahead and put it in a controller and now its working fine.. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!